# How do I get async code to wait until all tasks are complete?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.5

When I run the code below, the message `"Press Enter to continue... "` appears before the results are returned from the `HttpClient.GetAsync()` calls are completed. The actual sequence of events: the `GetAsync()` calls are made, the "`Press Enter...`" message appears, and then the results are one-by-one output to the console window. How do I wait until all the `GetAsync()` calls are complete before displaying the "`Press Enter...`" message?

```
class Program
{
  static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    RunAsync().Wait();

    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\nPress Enter to continue... ");
    Console.ReadLine();
  }

  static async Task RunAsync()
  {
    List<string> urls = new List<string>()
    {
      "http://www.domain1.com",
      "http://www.domain2.com",
      "http://www.domain3.com",
      "http://www.domain4.com"
    };

    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
      DownloadPageAsync(url);
    }
  }

  static async Task<string> DownloadPageAsync(string url)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Starting: " + url);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
      // do stuff here
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Done: " + url);

    return response.Content.ToString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `DownloadPageAsync` returns a task, you can make a list of all tasks and wait on them all:

```
Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(url => DownloadPageAsync(url)))
```

Or simplified:

```
Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(DownloadPageAsync))
```

Comment: What mechanism allows you to simplify it to `Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(DownloadPageAsync))`?  That's the first time I've encountered that format.

Comment: `Select` calls for an `Func<string, T>`, which `DownloadPageAsync` happens to be.

Comment: make sure you remove the `async` keyword from `RunAsync` and return the `Task.WhenAll(...)`

Comment: Also note that this is fine for small numbers of urls. If you plan on 100's or 1000's (such as a spider/crawler) then you'll need a more sophisticated approach that can limit concurrency.

Comment: Indeed, you could use `Semaphore` for that. 
@AndyPook

Comment: I was thinking more of a `Parallel.ForEach` with `MaxConcurrency` set or a custom `TaskScheduler`. Possibly using a `BlockingCollection` as an input queue and `GetConsumingEnumerable`.

Something like https://gist.github.com/AndyPook/cc91f90a20c807e39573

Answer (score 1):

The @patrik-hofman answer is a good one (up voted) although, see my comment

If you would rather the requests to happen sequentially...
Add `await` to the `DownloadPageAsync` line.

You've used `async` in `RunAsync` but there are no `await`s. So, although it returns a Task it is not waiting for the `DownloadPageAsync` call to complete. This means that the method simply returns an "empty" Task which completes immediately. So your `.Wait()` is waiting for nothing.

Comment: I tried  this suggestion and it seems the await causes the foreach to pause until DownloadPageAsync() completes before starting to process the next url. Is that correct?

Comment: correct. Using `await` here will cause all the requests to be sequential. If you want all the requests defined within your `RunAsync` method to happen in parallel then you need something like @partick-hofman suggests

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I think I tried this approach early on and removed the await to see what would happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not awaiting the `DownloadPageAsync` method inside the `RunAsync()` method.  If you update the `RunAsync()` method to the code below then I believe it will work as you expect:

```
static async Task RunAsync()
{
    List<string> urls = new List<string>()
    {
      "http://www.domain1.com",
      "http://www.domain2.com",
      "http://www.domain3.com",
      "http://www.domain4.com"
    };

    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        // added await here
        await DownloadPageAsync(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to create different tasks per every call you want, in your example you are running the code and not waiting for the call. When you call WhenAll that simply creates a task for all of them. Let's say that you use the code bellow and inside each MakeYouCall method you insert an item on a list. That list will be a shared resource that you need to lock. When the WhenAll is made, then if you don't wait for the result(make a call to Wait() ) then the collection could be partially filled.

```
var register1 = new Action(() => MakeYourCall1());
var register2 = new Action(() => MakeYourCall2());
var register3 = new Action(() => MakeYourCall3());
```

then

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(register1);
var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(register2);
var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(register3);
```

after that you can call the WhenAll that will return a Task, then wait for it.

```
Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3).Wait();
```